# How to raise max sanity?

Tags: dont-starve, dont-starve-together

After Maxewll summons a shadow puppet, his max sanity will go down, doing normal task like *picking flowers* to raise sanity won't raise it back up. Is there a way to raise his maximum sanity back to the normal 200?

Answer (score 4):

While the Shadow Puppet is active, your maximum Sanity is constantly lowered by 55 points and there is no way to regain that Sanity while you have the Shadow Puppet by your side. When the puppet dies, anyway, you will regain the lost maximum sanity [[source](http://dontstarve.wikia.com/wiki/Codex_Umbra)]